# Chrome Extension - Uncaught TypeError, If popup.js is in the manifest.json

Tags: google-chrome-extension

At first I thought it was the `chrome.tabs.query` as it's the first part of the popup.js and it is highlighted on the extensions error page. .

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'query')
[image]

Even after commenting it out and latter removing all code I still got the error when the page was first loaded or reloaded.

I ended up removing it from the manifest.json and even then I had to use the "Load unpacked" option but then the error was gone but the extension still worked.

```
  "content_scripts": [{
    "js": ["jquery-2.2.0.min.js", "popup.js"],
    "matches": ["https://www-*"]
  }]
```

I saw a demo that had it in the manifest.json, not sure if it should be there or not but it works without it.

I did not think you were putting them in the manifest.json to be run whenever the web page matched but so they would be available and or part of the extension.

Is it needed in the manifest.json and just ignore the errors?

I also went down the rabbit hole of not running the `chrome.tabs.query`function in a content.js but only a background.js, but found a fixe before getting that running.

Comment: Content scripts are only for web pages so you don't need them for your popup. Use the standard tag `<script src=popup.js></script>`

Comment: If you have `browser_action` or `action` popup in manifest.json then it's a different page, which is not related to web page, and it should use a separate independent script file.

Comment: Sorry new at this and I'm easily confused. The extension seems to work without the popup.js being in the manifest at all and that that removed the error message. What would adding it as a script in the manifest do? `<script src=popup.js></script>`

Comment: No, you need to remove it from manifest.json. You already load it in your popup.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `chrome.tabs` in content scripts, only in background ones.

Check the [Chrome official documenation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/) for more information